# Get BuddyPress activity parent user name

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm looking for a way to display the user name who's been replied to, rather than displaying a comment tree.

Now it's like:

> user1: hey
>
> > user2: hello :)
> >
> > > user3: what's up dude?

I want to display the comments like this:

```
user1: hey
user2: @user1 hello :)
user3: @user2 what's up dude?
```

I found this function in bp-activity-template.php:

```
function bp_activity_parent_user_id() {
    echo bp_get_activity_parent_user_id();
}
```

But I have to call in that function in the comment.php file, and it's not working. (neither bp_activity_parent_user_id(); or echo bp_get_activity_parent_user_id();)

```
<div class="reply-to">
        <?php bp_activity_parent_user_id(); ?>
</div>
```

I'm kind of stuck here, any help will be appreciated.